# (VBA) (Excel) Get and count unique values in a column

Tags: excel, vba

Hello everyone and have a good day! =)

I have a table with a column (say A:A) i want to get unique values from, count them and write them down, i have:

```
Russian Federation
Italy
USA
Estonia
Belarus
Netherlands
Russian Federation
Russian Federation
Russian Federation
USA
USA
Russian Federation
Russian Federation
```

Is there some way in VBA to write for example in neighbouring column (say cell B1 or column B:B, how's easier) this:

```
Russian Federation 6
Italy 1
USA 3
Estonia 1
Belarus 1
Netherlands 1
```

Thank you much in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is. What did you try on your own?

Comment: Hi, for this case maybe you need to use the pivot table?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It will return in columns "B:C":

```
Sub uniqueValuesAA()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, dict As Object 
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   arr = Range("A1:A" & lastR).Value
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   For i = 1 To lastR
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) + 1
   Next i
   arrFin = Application.Transpose(Array(dict.Keys, dict.items))
   sh.Range("B1").Resize(dict.count, 2).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```